# RowVersion value is not getting binded in form data, mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, concurrency, optimistic-concurrency, rowversion

I am trying to implement concurrency using EF6 in MVC 5.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion)
```

On my edit page I am able to see the rowversion value in input type hidden.

```
 <input id="RowVersion" name="RowVersion" type="hidden" value="AAAAAAAAF3M=">
```

But on $('form').serializeArray() I am not getting RowVersion data, on posting the form also I am getting null value of RowVersion property.

I had added RowVersion column in database table later and updated the edmx after that, I have set concurrency mode to fixed in the primary key column property my table in edmx.

Is there something extra that needs to be done for rowversion ?
Any help would be appreciated.

**Update :** adding html code

Jquery : I am checking it in console using : $('form').serializeArray()

html output from browser :

```
        <form action="/Master/EditBookMaster/13" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Y04ae_LHgfG9Tw9hy2TcHIYbxk_EX_vykyphV7Sm9Wwiz6_f8PpGUY2SULyiZbCdJv4fgBloOlx_QRUz1FQNvXTZUorLt6_EvA9XLxcFsxbQqUlmY9XOCduHa__q1kdRQJpFAx4wOuj5tRu48TLh9A2" />    <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>BookMaster</h4>
                <hr />

                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field BookMasterId must be a number." data-val-required="The BookMasterId field is required." id="BookMasterId" name="BookMasterId" type="hidden" value="13" />

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="BookName">BookName</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="BookName" name="BookName" type="text" value="C Programming" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="BookName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Count">Count</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Count must be a number." data-val-required="The Count field is required." id="Count" name="Count" type="number" value="10" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Count" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Publisher">Publisher</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Publisher" name="Publisher" type="text" value="Dennis-Ritchie" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Publisher" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Subject">Subject</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SubjectId must be a number." data-val-required="The SubjectId field is required." id="SubjectId" name="SubjectId"><option value="1">Fiction</option>
        <option value="2">Biography</option>
        <option value="3">Science</option>
        <option value="4">Research</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="5">Software developement</option>
        </select>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SubjectId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AvailableCount">AvailableCount</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AvailableCount must be a number." id="AvailableCount" name="AvailableCount" type="number" value="8" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="AvailableCount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
  <div>
 <a href="/Master/Index">Back to List</a>
  </div>
  <input id="RowVersion" name="RowVersion" type="hidden" value="AAAAAAAAF3M=" />
```

Comment: Post HTML and Javascript code.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov added it

Comment: And where is RowVersion input and Javascript code?

Comment: updated it, rowversion input type is beneath the form closing tag(i think it should have been inside) 
there's no javascript code, I am checking the output in $('form').serializeArray() in console only for test.

Comment: Simply put rowversion input inside form tag.

Comment: yep, it worked.... you solved it in just 10 minutes from I guess 10000 miles away...thanks

Comment: @Rajdeep: Simply put the hidden field inside the form tag

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":input,:hidden").serialize();
```

code instead of

```
$('form').serializeArray()
```

[image: Click here to view preview.]